# All documents moved to sub-folder for iCloud

Tags: icloud

I turned on iCloud for my documents and all of them were moved into a sub-folder.
[image]

I don't want to have to navigate to another layer of documents. How do I fix this so iCloud keeps everything in my original documents folder?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332172/create-a-symbolic-link-to-desktop-and-documents-folder-in-icloud-drive?rq=1